# Gitflow strategy for multiple released versions of a project

Tags: tfs, version-control, project, branching-and-merging, git-flow

I am designing a branching & merging strategy for my project (We use TFS). Project has plans to have multiple released versions. Currently we are testing v1.0alpha and working in v2.0

The plan is:

- After imminent green light from testers, **version v1.0** will be released to one client.
- **Version v1.1** (already in dev) will be deployed to 5-6 clients
- **Version v1.2** would be installed to dozens of clients.
- etc.

We will try to force upgrade of old clients to most recent versions but due to the nature of project and market it can be months (years?) for clients to upgrade.

We want to use standard gitflow but seems more appropriate for having a single version. I have designed a simplification of gitflow:
[image: Git Flow simplification]

The approach is:

- If a client wants a bug fixed, we will fix it in the Release branch of his version and he has to upgrade to the latest revision of his version. For example client in v1.0 that has a bug would have to upgrade to v1.0.5. If the bug happens in other versions we will fix it there.
- If the client wants a **new feature** we will develop it in the latest version and force them to upgrade if they want it. For example client in v1.0.5 that wants new version will have to upgrade to v1.2
- If all the clients of a given version upgrade we will delete that Release branch. For example when the client of v1.0 upgrades we will burminate v1.0 Release branch.

So my questions in order of importance are:

1. Will my approach work? Any problems that you can see?
2. Does git-flow have any pattern for this "multiple versions scenario"?
3. Gitflow has a Master branch. Is it ok not having a Master branch? Could we consider the different Release branches as "Master"?
4. How will you name Dev and Releases branches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your approach should work.  There is nothing magical to GitFlow, and variations catering to your needs are fine.  Git itself has no issues with a different workflow.  A good example is Github flow, take a look at http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html .

A few things you could consider:

a) "Principle of least surprise":  Try to keep as close to a standard as you can. That means you i) point devs to available documentation on the web instead of writing up everything ii) make it easier for new devs to enter or just work with your projects.
Thus, you should keep the master branch, not because it is needed - it is not, but because it might confuse people when it is not there, and you would have to explain that for years to come.
Branches in git is "just" names (well, a bit more, but you get my meaning), so the only reason to name them the same is convention - making it easy for people.

b) How many devs are working on the projects?  If there are many, you could consider the Dev branch an integration branch, and use the master branch as the stable branch.  Having a dev branch that you allow to be unstable might solve many issues with many devs.  Two teams committing, one from feature and one from a hotfix,  the build goes red, the teams blaming each other, the third team try to get out a new release branch, but can't.   Having a stable, always green build master branch, which you even could protect with pull requests, is very nice, and makes for a more relaxed environment.

2) Basic Gitflow is centered around a release, so not quite.   You have multiple releases at the same time.  So you are nearly there, but standard tools, like [Jakob Ehn's] (https://github.com/jakobehn) [Gitflow extention to Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f5ae0a1d-005f-4a09-a19c-3f46ff30400a) - which is supergreat - will make you try to close a release before you are allowed to open a new one.  Ask Jakob to relax that, and the tool will work for you.  Otherwise, just follow the convention, but do it manually - that works too.

3) See point 1 above about master and why it might not be a good idea to not have it.  But of course you can consider the release branches as kind of masters, but they don't really behave that way in your description.  And if so, which one is the real master, the one you create feature branches from, and the one you regard as the latest?  Having a stable master solves a lot of questions that pops up without.

4) Dev or Develop, then features should have a name of the feature as close to what it does as possible, like Dev/NewHelpPage, or Feature/NewHelpPage (to be closer to gitflow convention). Release branches, it looks like you already follow the semantic versioning (http://semver.org) principle, so why not use that:  Release/V1.0,  Release/V1.1 and so on.  A hotfix branch is then Release/V1.0.1 .
Let the naming be so that devs easily understand what it is, preferably without needing to have to ask anyone around.

Keep it simple, follow conventions as far as you can, and it tends to work out.  Git itself works for mostly any branching scheme.

[Edit]
Just had a quick chat with Jakob, and he said he had requests to support support-branches, which is probably what you are really after.  He also pointed to [this excellent post](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/git-branching-strategies/gitflow-examples/) on different gitflow scenarios, at the bottom there is the flow for support-branches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-)